# How To Deploy SQL Server Reporting Services With Forms Authentication?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I can't get forms authentication to work for SSRS.

[MSDN Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281383.aspx)

I have followed the instructions in the above link except for #12 which I don't understand and can't follow.  There are three config files to change and the instructions are quite straightforward.  But when I access the reporting site with the virtual directory URL, instead of being directed to a login.aspx I get:

"StringStartsWith can't accept null parameters"

My virtual directory URL works fine with windows authentication, but I want to incorporate the report viewer into a forms-authenticated website and don't want to add an additional windows login.  Since forms authentication failed, I tried using the reportviewer ASP control instead -- with no luck -- I get an error on that aswell --- appears you need code not well documented for passing windows authentication to the reporting service.

Has anyone gotten SSRS working successfully with forms authentication and/or reportviewer control using SQL Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score -1):

Download and follow the example on http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/.